# yup condition for password in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik-material-ui

password: Yup.string()

```
    .matches(
    "^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#!@$%^&*()+=]).{8,20}$",
    `Should contains at least 8 characters and at most 20 characters\n 
    Should contains at least one digit\n 
    Should contains at least one upper case alphabet\n 
    Should contains at least one lower case alphabet\n
    Should contains at least one special character which includes !@#$%&*()+=^\n
    Should  contain  white space`
    )
    .required("Password is required")
```

in the text field it can not take white space except white space it take all  symbols and characters .how to enable the white space field. If I want to write Pass @ 123 its not able to type?